# Clean way of checking if resource exists and if user can edit it

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have two very common steps that I have to repeat in almost every CRUD method in my Controllers. I have my Users split into 2 groups `( Users, Administrators )`. Now Users can `edit, update and delete` only their own entries while admins can do all the CRUD operations.

The second piece of code I find my self writing every time is checking if the resource exist which is repetitive and somewhat annoying.

Here is what I attempted:

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller
{
  // Received Eloquent model each model has user_id field
  public function authorize($resource)
  {
    // Check if currently logged in users id matches user_id
    // value of the resource
    if($resource->user_id !== CurrentUser::getUser()->id)
    {
      // Users id does not match with resource user_id check if user is admin
      if(!CurrentUser::getGroup() === 'Admin')
      {
        // The id's do not match and user is not admin redirect him back to root
        Session::flash('error', 'You cannot edit this resource');
        return Redirect::to('/');
      }
    }
  }  
} 

class CarController extends BaseController
{
  public function edit($id)
  {
    // Attempt to find the resource
    $car = Car::find($id);

    // Check if found
    if(!$car)
    {
      // Resource was not found
      Session::flash('error', 'Resource was not found');
      return Redirect::to('/cars');
    }

    // First check if user is allowed to edit the resource
    // this however does not work because returned Redirect is simply ignored I would
    // have to return boolean and then check it but...
    $this->authorize($car); 

    // ... rest of the code
  }
}
```

This would not be a problem if I had 3-4 methods but I have some 6-10 methods and as you can see this part takes some 20 lines of code add that 6-10 times not to mention it's repetitive to the point where it get's annoying.

I have tried to solve the problem using a filter but the problem is that I can pass the id to the filter but not get it to work in a way that I would pass the model as well.

There has to be a cleaner way to implement all this. I'm somewhat happy with `authorize` function/process but it would be awesome not having to call is every time possibly having some filter and each controller would define global variable/array of methods that require authorization.

As for checking if record was found I was hoping maybe a filter could be done to catch all `RecordNotFound` exceptions and redirect back to controllers index route with a message.

Comment: You could use the findOrFail method instead of the find method, so an exception is thrown automatically if the requested model does not exist.

Comment: @peaceman 
Hm don't know how I missed that one this solves the record find problem. So basically just sticking App::error() in the routes file ? I'm guessing I could do the same with authorize method just have it throw an exception and then I could catch it with App::error(UnauthorizedException).

Comment: @peaceman 

Only problem I have with that solution is say RecordNotFound but it's fired so I catch it I can only redirect back to root since I have no idea which Controller fired up the Exception. Like I would need to know say if CarsController fired up the exception then redirect to '/cars' if PartsController then redirect to '/parts' etc..

Comment: @MitchGlenn I'm guessing you commented in a wrong thread : D

Comment: @kellax You could overwrite the controller method callAction and wrap parent::callAction with a try/catch block, so you can catch the RecordNotFound exception and redirect to a different url that is defined for example in a controller property.

Comment: @peaceman Good notice. I chose a bit simpler way. I have ModelNotFoundException now this will be triggered when something is posted to a route with id that does not exist well in my function(..Exception $e){} What I do is Session::flash('error', Lang::get('errors.not_found_' . Request::segment(1)); as well as return Redirect::to('/' . Request::segment(1)); Now if someone requested Car resource the route will be '/cars/id' well this will simply return them to '/cars' route and show the not_found_cars message.

Comment: @peaceman I'm going with your idea so if you want you can post it and I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use findOrFail() and catch the exception in your BaseController and you also have two options:

```
try
{
    $post = $this->post->findOrFail($id);

    return View::make('posts.show', compact('post'));
}
catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    return Redirect::route('posts.index');
}
```

Or

```
$post = $this->post->findOrFail($id);

return View::make('posts.show', compact('post'));
```

And a exception handler returning back to your form with the input:

```
App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $exception)
{
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors()->withInput();
});
```

Note that those are just examples, not took from your code.